# Why is my angular filter not filtering all appropriate objects? Angular - angular-ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a `filter` in my `uib-typeahead`  The `ng-options` portion looks like this

```
<input
    ng-model="mergeParticipant"
    getDisplayValue(value.name, value.age, value.membershipId) for value in participants | filter:$viewValue"
                                />
```

The function that is being called to format the display is here:

```
    $scope.getDisplayValue = (name, age, membershipId) => {
        return age ? `${name} (${age}) - ${membershipId}`: `${name} - ${membershipId}`;
    };
```

When I type in the letters `bi` into my input, here is my result:

[image]

Why is the entry without `bi` showing up in my list?  I thought it might have something to do with the numbers on the screen, but I couldn't find any pattern there.  Any ideas?

Comment: probably has `bi` in another property not shown

Comment: You are correct.  How do you choose to search only what is being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your list is something like this:

```
$scope.list = [
    {id:1, title: 'a'},
    {id:2, title: 'b'},
    {id:3, title: 'c'},
]
```

You can choose which key you want to apply your filter like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchKey" />

<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:{title: searchKey}"></li>
</ul>
```